# What is the meaning of null in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

Been plotting things with Grafana with prometheus as datasource. One thing that i am not really clear about is null and Nan values. I wonder:

1. What is the meaning of null in prometheus ?
2. When can a time series return the value null ?
3. Is the value null the same NaN ?
4. In grafana, graph panel we can interpret null as zero, as null, or connected ? What does that mean exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus has no notion of "null", if there's no data for a given step then there's there's no data - which Grafana will consider as null if there's data for a series at another step.

NaN in Prometheus is simply a number, usually occurring if you divide by zero.